# Hard coding of refactoring move and extract method, parsing class and its references?

Tags: java, eclipse, parsing, refactoring, automated-refactoring

Currently, I am working on research about refactoring tasks and its prioritization. I need to examine effects of each task (for example, move method, extract method, delete method) and to do some calculation on class and project level.

What is the best way of approaching these tasks manually, on code level?

I was thinking on building Eclipse plugin on top of its main application that open refactor menu and do refactoring tasks, but it doesn't seem good method, I need closer relation to code of each class.

Other way, I was thinking to build a plugin that parses each class and its references and does ref. tasks while parsing? This approach seems more appropriate to me since I need to automate the process and do some calculation.

What is the common way of programming/coding refactoring tasks (move, extract and delete method)? I am working on Java.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear what you are trying to do.
With Eclipse JDT, APIs exist to run the manual refactorings: http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Frefactoring%2FIJavaRefactorings.html

I have seen a research paper describing the impact of suchrefactorings on power consumption.

Otherwise you can look at [AutoRefactor](https://github.com/JnRouvignac/AutoRefactor) for an example of how to use JDT for doing refactorings. Disclaimer: I am the author of AutoRefactor.

Comment: First of all, thank you for answer, I will look at references and come back to add more here. I want to execute each ref. task, calculate some metrics and based on it, continue or stop with next task and I am looking for the most appropriate way of coding it. For AutoRefactor, I came across your paper published in Expert Systems with Applications and good work, I wished it could handle more bad smells (as i remember, only 3 were there?!).

Comment: I did not publish any paper :) Do you have a reference by any chance?

Comment: :-) http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0957417414005612, it seems that _AutoRefactoring_ is the name of published platform, then I mixed tools. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Alas I cannot get access to any free pdf and their github repository is surprisingly already dead :( Anyway, thanks for bringing this to my attention. That would be great if I could read that article!

Comment: You may contact author of the paper for their legal copy, most of the will share their work.

Comment: Thanks, I actually asked someone I know who works in research :)

Answer (score 0):

The most general refactoring tools are [Program Transformation Systems (PTS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation).
These are tools that read source code, build compiler data structures (often ASTs) representing that code, allow custom modifications to those structures, and can then regenerated code from the modified structures.

Good PTSes can be configured to handle arbitrary langauges, and will let you write code transformation in terms of source-to-source transformations using the surface syntax of the target langauge, in the following form:

```
 when you see *thispattern*, replace it by *thatpattern* if *condition*
```

Such tools can carry out arbitrary code refactorings in the small, or even architectural code changes or langauge migrations in the large.

[See my bio for one of these].

Comment: It will be very interesting if I could afford more time to make it more general and more formal, especially being able to verify preservation of behavior of refactored program using formal specification and formal semantics, but, unfortunately, for now, I need it on the "code-to-code" level, with as simple as possible coding because my research is on the step after that. Thx for pointing me to your bio, a lot of interesting and eye-open articles. Kindly, what do you think about parsing Java program, searching for specific element id and reusing and applying eclipse refactoring task on it?

Comment: Read "LifeAfterParsing" via my bio.   Eclipse should be OK at allowing you to write procedural code to hack at ASTs.   Program transformation engines let you "hack" at ASTs writing patterns which makes it significantly easier.

Comment: I don't know where "formal specs and verification" got into this discussion; I didn't bring it up.   A PTS does not provide an specific support for this.  But then, no refactoring tool I've ever seen, and no compiler, offer such support (with the exception of really rare academic paper on such a tools).  PTS's are about *practical* application of code-to-code transformations.

Comment: I brought it, that path was in my mind while thinking about refactoring and behavior preservation and PTS. Formal spec and ver could help with assuring/proving that behavior of the system did not change after ref. tasks, that was just in my mind, I would think twice before even starting to go that way. I need more "common" way of how ref. tasks are done, I need it as a input for my next step in algorithm.

Comment: Current refactoring tools are largely built the same way compilers are built: the source text is parsed, some AST is built, the AST is analyzed and changed, all using pure procedural code.   That kind of stuff is incredibly hard to "prove" correct.  Now, you either want to build refactoring tools, or you want to prove them correct.  Pick one, you don't have time for both in the next 10 years.  ("Algorithm"? what algorithm?)    *Have you had a compiler class?*  No?  Start there.

Comment: :-) Maybe it is my fault, let us simplify it. I am not building ref. tool nor proving it correct. I need to execute 1000s of 1000s of ref tasks automatically and analyze them. _Algorithm_ in terms that ref. tasks are only part of my input, step 1 of my research. _compiler class_, I need to think about it, it was before a while.

Comment: Analyzer refinement tasks to achieve what purpose?  Why is there a need to analyze thousands (of possibly not very different) instances?

Comment: For purpose, you name it. Reduce time effort, improve maintainability, limit number of ref. tasks, any general SE goal. Executing 1000s of ref. tasks is matter of learning part of algorithm, more it learns, more is able to generalize.

Comment: What "it" learning algorithm? You just don't make one up out of thin air, that magically "learns" great properties of complex systems.   The more you write, the  more confused I get about the definition and realism of your goals, and your ability to do something specific.   At this point I have no clue about what you intend to do or how you intend to do it.  Do you have a specific task in mind?  Otherwise this conversation stops.

Comment: Maybe it is better to stop conversation.

Comment: Too many people bet on machine learning to do something they don't know how to do.   I think ML can do some things, but I'm not a big believer that it can do things that require "theorem prover correctness", that is, reason correctly about things that have complex conditions (syntax, esp. semantics) or make complex changes to code.  Could you get some approximation wth ML?  Maybe.   You want Google to use ML to implement your driverless car, and get some code that approximately works?